save tensorflow model using transfer learning
I am trying to save a model which uses transfer_learning but I'm unable to make it work once I reconstruct it. This is my code:
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tf_keras as tfk
import os
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
directory = "brain_tumor_dataset"
images = []
labels = []
for category in os.listdir(directory):
    rute_category = os.path.join(directory, category)
    for image_name in os.listdir(rute_category):
        image_rute = os.path.join(rute_category, image_name)
        image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(image_rute, target_size=(224,224))
        image_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image) / 255.0  
        images.append(image_array)
        labels.append(1 if category == "yes" else 0)
images = np.array(images)
labels = np.array(labels)
X_training, X_testing, y_training, y_testing = train_test_split(images, labels, test_size=0.3,     random_state=42)
url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_140_224/feature_vector/5"
movilenetv2 = hub.KerasLayer(url, input_shape=(224,224,3), trainable=False)
model = tfk.Sequential([
    movilenetv2,
    tfk.layers.Dense(2,activation="softmax")
])
model.compile(
    optimizer="adam",
    loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
    metrics = ["accuracy"]
)
training = model.fit(
    X_training,
    y_training,
    epochs=20,
    validation_data = (X_testing, y_testing)
)
model.save("my_model.h5")
reconstructured_model = keras.models.load_model("my_model.h5", custom_objects = {"KerasLayer": hub.KerasLayer})`

The error I get is: ValueError: Only instances of `keras.Layer` can be added to a Sequential model. Received: <tensorflow_hub.keras_layer.KerasLayer object at 0x000002AA80E59FD0> (of type <class 'tensorflow_hub.keras_layer.KerasLayer'>)
The model works as it is but the reconstructed model doesn't
I had tried saving it as .keras or .h5 but nothing worked

Could you please share the dataset?

Hi @Lorenze , you are facing the issue to save a model with a Keras Layer, you can use savemodel to save it model.save("sample.keras", save_format='keras') after that you need to load the model with custom_objects correctly.Try this and if you need any more help, let me know. Thank you
